# Audio Play Pause Toggle Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you have an svg image that changes color slightly when hovered over and when clicked toggle switches to another svg image that can then be switched back to the original by clicking again (same hover effect). When clicked it should play/pause a source audio file.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/jbwhr7n9/1/embed/js,html,css,result/dark/"></script>
```

This is what I have so far, I've been looking over how to do this and can't find a clear answer for this use-case.

Comment: i guess you will need javascript to switch button images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added jQuery to play and pause the audio, hide and show the buttons.

```js
$('#play').click(function() {
  $('#audio-file').trigger('play');
  $(this).hide();
  $('#pause').show();
});

$('#pause').click(function() {
  $('#audio-file').trigger('pause');
  $(this).hide();
  $('#play').show();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #242626
}
.blockA {
     border: 6px solid #181919;
     background: #181919;
}
.blockB {
     border: 6px solid #2c3030;
     background: #2c3030;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
.blockC {
     border: 6px solid #242626;
     background: #242626;
}
.titleHover {
     border: 4px solid transparent;
     width: 200px;
     height: 301px;
     display: block;
}
.titleHover > img {
     max-width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
.titleHover:hover {
     border-color: #49bdba;
}
a:link {
     color: #49bdba;
     background: transparent;
}
a:visited {
     color: #49bdba;
}
a:hover {
     color: #49bdba;
     background: transparent;
}
a:active {
}
.sBC {
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}

.sBB1, .sBB2, .sBB3 {
width: 35px;
height: 5px;
background-color: #333;
margin: 6px 0;
transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change .sBB1 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .sBB2 {
opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .sBB3 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}
ul {
background-color: #181919;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 1;
}
.btn-secondary {
color: #fff;
background-color: #242626;
border-color: #242626;
}
.btn-secondary:focus {
box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.blockD {
display: inline-block;
}

.bottom-bar {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.mbuttonhover {
  fill: #49bdba;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mbuttonhover:hover {
  fill: rgb(36,100,98);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<audio src="https://d3cj65qhk7sagp.cloudfront.net/tracks/Beacon/Faux+Tales+-+Beacon.mp3" id="audio-file"></audio>
<div class="blockA">
  <div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 150 150" width="10%" height="10%" class="mbuttonhover active" id="play"><defs><clipPath id="_clipPath_yKzkJPlSAzMkZT8ai7ySqD3TM8Th7XOR"><rect width="100%" height="100%"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#_clipPath_yKzkJPlSAzMkZT8ai7ySqD3TM8Th7XOR)"><path class="expand" d=" M 130.884 81.689 L 78.986 111.95 L 27.087 142.212 C 19.761 146.484 13.804 143.067 13.794 134.586 L 13.722 75.049 L 13.65 15.513 C 13.64 7.032 19.626 3.535 27.008 7.709 L 78.895 37.047 L 130.783 66.386 C 138.165 70.56 138.211 77.417 130.884 81.689 Z "/></g></svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate; display: none;" viewBox="0 0 150 150" width="10%" height="10%" class="mbuttonhover" id="pause"><defs><clipPath id="_clipPath_r5GZgsezpi491ktbWcAvoJzmMQuyG3g9"><rect width="150" height="150"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#_clipPath_r5GZgsezpi491ktbWcAvoJzmMQuyG3g9)"><path d=" M 20.76 15 L 57.24 15 C 60.419 15 63 17.581 63 20.76 L 63 129.24 C 63 132.419 60.419 135 57.24 135 L 20.76 135 C 17.581 135 15 132.419 15 129.24 L 15 20.76 C 15 17.581 17.581 15 20.76 15 Z  M 92.76 15 L 129.24 15 C 132.419 15 135 17.581 135 20.76 L 135 129.24 C 135 132.419 132.419 135 129.24 135 L 92.76 135 C 89.581 135 87 132.419 87 129.24 L 87 20.76 C 87 17.581 89.581 15 92.76 15 Z "/></g></svg>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```